# SQL Server : code created and not sure why it is not processing - foreign key problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE THREE_GIRLS_COFFEE_HUT 
(
    ShopName    Char        NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber Char(12)    NOT NULL,
    Address     Char(20)    NOT NULL,
    City        Char(20)    NOT NULL,
    State       Char(2)     NOT NULL,
    ZipCode     Char(5)     NOT NULL,    

    CONSTRAINT ShopPK PRIMARY KEY (ShopName)
);

 CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
 (
    EmployeeID   Int        NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    EmployeeName Char(30)   NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber  Char(10)   NOT NULL,
    Address      Char(20)   NOT NULL,
    City         Char(20)   NOT NULL,
    State        Char(2)    NOT NULL,
    ZipCode      Char(5)    NOT NULL,
    EmployeeType Char(10)   NOT NULL,
    ShopName     Char (25)  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES THREE_GIRLS_COFFEE_HUT (ShopName)    
    CONSTRAINT EmployeePK  PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID),
    CONSTRAINT EmployeeAK1 UNIQUE(EmployeeName)
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
    CustomerID   Int      NOT NULL IDENTITY(1000,1),
    CustomerName Char(30) NULL,
    PhoneNumber  Char(10) NULL,
    EmailAddress Char(30) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT CustomerPK  PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID),
    CONSTRAINT CustomerAK1 UNIQUE(EmailAddress)
);    

CREATE TABLE [ORDER] 
(
    SalesOrderNumber INT            NOT NULL IDENTITY (1500,1),
    Date             Numeric(6)     NOT NULL,
    Subtotal         Numeric(6, 2)  NOT NULL,
    Tax              Numeric(6, 2)  NOT NULL,
    Total            Numeric(6, 2)  NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT OrderPK  PRIMARY KEY (SalesOrderNumber),
    CONSTRAINT EmpOrdFK FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID)
                        REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID)
                        ON UPDATE CASCADE 
                        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT CustOrdFK FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)
                         REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerID)
                         ON UPDATE NO ACTION
                         ON DELETE NO ACTION
);    

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT 
(
    ProductNumber       Int             NOT NULL IDENTITY(2000,1),
    ProductDescription  Char(20)        NOT NULL,
    QuantityOnOrder     Numeric(4)      NOT NULL,
    QuantityOnHand      Numeric(4)      NOT NULL,
    OrderDate           Date            NOT NULL,
    ExpirationDate      Date            NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT  ProductPK               PRIMARY KEY(ProductNumber),
    CONSTRAINT  ValidExpDate            CHECK   (ExpirationDate > OrderDate)
);

CREATE TABLE MENU_ITEM (
    ItemNumber      Int                 NOT NULL IDENTITY(3000,1),
    ItemDescription Char(30)            NOT NULL,
    ItemCost        Numeric(6,2)        NOT NULL,
    ProductNumber   Int                 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PRODUCT(ProductNumber)

    CONSTRAINT  MenuPK                  PRIMARY KEY(ItemNumber),
    CONSTRAINT  MenuAK1                 UNIQUE(ItemDescription),    
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER_LINE_ITEM (
    SalesOrderNumber    INT             FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [ORDER](SalesOrderNumber),
    ItemNumber          INT             FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MENU_ITEM(ItemNumber), 
    Quantity            Numeric         NOT NULL,
    UnitPrice           Numeric(6,2)    NOT NULL,
    ExtendedPrice       Numeric (6,2)   NOT NULL,
);
```

I got these errors and it will not process- I think I have problem with my foreign key but I am not sure.

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
>   Foreign key 'EmpOrdFK' references invalid column 'EmployeeID' in referencing table 'ORDER'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 40
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: I would highly recommend not calling a table `ORDER` either, since its a keyword and will have to be always quoted - easy to make a mistake.

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know, there is no column called `EmployeeID` in table `ORDER`

Answer (score 0):

There's no column EmployeeID in the ORDER table, so:

```
EmpOrdFK FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID)
```

which says, create a foreign key in which Order.EmployeeId references Employee.EmployeeId, can't work.

Did you want to add an EmployeeId column to Order?

(There's also no CustomerId in Order, so the next line

```
  CONSTRAINT      CustOrdFK       FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)
```

would have failed too, except it never got to run because of the first error.)

You probably want to add EmployeeId and CustomerId to the Order table.

Answer (score 0):

When you are mapping foreign key from Order table to Employee table, you have to map on common column in both tables. If you look at order table, which is missing employeeId in 
that table. 
And also don't call it as ORDER table. ORDER is reserved keyword in SQL server.

References: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15